# Slider Button Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, slider

I have a slider that works perfectly with the exception of getting the disk to animate to the corresponding slide. I think since I have the slides changing their number for the infinite loop it messes with how the disc buttons select them. If anyone has a fix please fork my code.

http://codepen.io/Spiderian/pen/IKvah

Here is the code in question:

```
discs.click(function(e)
{
  console.log( slideAnimating );


  var btnIndex = discs.index(this);


  if(!slideAnimating && btnIndex !== slideNumber)
  {

    timerFunction.pause();


    nextSlide = btnIndex;


    changeSlide();
  }
```

Comment: (OT) You realize that this kind of indentation makes souls fill with agony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not in discs.click but in changeSlide().

With this edit it will works:

```
function changeSlide()
{

  slideAnimating = true;

  console.log( "slide out => " + slideNumber );
  console.log( "slide IN => " + nextSlide + "\n" );

  currentDisk = nextSlide; // Edit #1

  TweenMax.to( discs.eq(slideNumber), 1, {backgroundColor:"#ffffff", borderColor:"#f10000"});

  TweenMax.to(slides[slideNumber], duration,
    {
      left:"-100%",
      onComplete:function()
      {

        slideAnimating = false;

        timerFunction.restart(true);

        if( wrapper.hasClass( "mouse-over" ) )
        {
          timerFunction.pause();
        }

        TweenMax.set(this.target, {left:"100%"});
      }
    });

  TweenMax.fromTo( discs.eq(currentDisk), 1, {backgroundColor:"#ffffff", borderColor:"#f10000"}, {backgroundColor:"#f10000", borderColor:"#ffffff"});

  TweenMax.to(slides[nextSlide], duration,
    {
      left:"0%"
    });

  if( nextSlide < totalSlides -1 )
  {

    slideNumber = nextSlide;

    nextSlide++;
  }
  else
  {

    slideNumber = nextSlide;

    nextSlide = 0;
    console.log("first slide!!");
  }

}
```